# Page Reload for Opera

Tags: javascript, reload

I'm trying to get this page reload function to work in the new Opera v12.  The function allows you to click away from a page & then come back and at that point the page is reloaded with a clean cache, ie fresh.  What do I need to change to get it to work for Opera?

```
window.onload = function() {
  var rel = document.getElementById('forme').toBeReloaded.value; //get the current var value
  if (rel==1) {  // retrieved from the server (reloaded)
    if ($.browser.webkit || $.browser.msie) {
    window.location.reload(); //loaded from the cache
    }
    if ($.browser.mozilla) {
      buttonPlace();
      console.log('Firefox Reload: ');
    }
    if ($.browser.opera) {
      window.location.reload(true);
      console.log('Opera Reload: ');
    }
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('forme').toBeReloaded.value = 1;
  }
}
```

Thanks, Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out using document ready and:

```
$(function() {
    var rel = $('[name=toBeReloaded]');
    if(rel.val() == 1) {
      rel.val(0);
      if ($.browser.opera) {
        location.href = location.href;  // reload
      }  
      else {
        location.href = location.href;  // reload
      }      
    }
    else {
    rel.val(1);
    }
  });
```

Bill